# Expo Developer Tools is disconnected from Expo CLI. Cannot find module './validators/Presets'

Tags: react-native

i'm new to react-native. i've been tryin to set up a new react-native project, but seems to have some problem. I saw many questions similar to this, but none of it is relevent to the issue i'm experiencing..

i've installed and created expo as per documentation.

```sh
npm i -g expo-cli
expo init testproject
cd testproject
```

[image]
[image]

but when i expo start, the above error occurs

```
npm: 6.9.0
node: 12.1.0
expo: 2.15.4
```

expo diagnostics:[image]

Comment: Check this, I think this might be helpful for you https://github.com/expo/web-examples/issues/29

Comment: @AddWebSolutionPvtLtd. thanks for the guidance..

Answer (score 0):

as per guidance mentioned by

> @AddWeb Solution Pvt Ltd

, i was able to fix the issue.
thanks..
for anyone stumbling with the same issue in future, i'm leaving the answer here.

The problem is with linux O.S. it's case-sensitive. so the fix is to manually edit 
'Colors' to 'colors' and 'Presets' to 'presets' which is shown in the below image[image]

Comment: It’d be better to copy/paste your code here instead of posting a screenshot.